# My Heatmap is not looking correct with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have some data in a dictionary:

```
extension   number of
=====================
  .pdf        10
  .txt        5
  .doc        23
  .png        15
```

I'm looking for creative ways to visualize this so I wanted to test it out on a heat map.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(extensions)
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True)

>>> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

If I pass an index=[0] like described in other answers, it doesn't look right, see image below:

[image]

Comment: How does it look? What is wrong with it? How do you want to change it?

Comment: @kindall I've added an image above, what do you think? I was hoping for the separate squares like you normally see.